# How to redirect 419 page default Laravel in ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

i want to redirect 419 page when user opens new tab and logout, after they click button submit => redirect 419 page
I am currently doing the following:

```
        if (jqXHR.status === 419) {
            return window.location = laroute.route('cms.login');
        }
```

I want to redirect to screen 419 page expired instead of login screen

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a route like this and redirect to that route.

```
Route::get('expired', function () {
    abort('419');
})->name('error.expired');
```

I don't know if there is a better way of handeling this.